# Loop through directories and subdirectories in bash

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I tried with this line, starting at the parent folder containing the folders I want to loop through:

```
for dir in */; do  
    cd $dir  
    for dir2 in */; do  
        cd $dir2  
        ls -d $PWD/*  
        cd ..  
    done  
    cd ..  
done
```

But it just outputs the whole contents of my whole computer and goes back to root folder /~ ... any explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Depending where you start it, the behaviour you describe seems to match what it does.  The `find` command might be a better option depending on what you are trying to accomplish, so at least the script doesn't try to cd into files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bash`'s default "globbing" (wildcard matching/expansion) behavior is to return the wildcard expression itself if the wildcard doesn't match anything. So if you `cd` into a directory that has no subdirectories, you'll end up trying to `cd` into literally '*/' (literally a directory whose name is an asterisk), and that will fail, so you'll stay one directory higher than you thought you'd be at this point in the loop. So when you then `cd ..`, you'll be one directory higher again. Eventually you'll back yourself out to the root level of your filesystem.

Many shell scripters choose to use `find(1)` rather than shell loops when they want to have a script walk a directory tree. Your whole script snippet would become:

```
find . -type d
```

…or, if you really wanted absolute paths rather than relative paths:

```
find "$PWD" -type d
```

If you want to stick with shell loops for this, you might try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -evx
for dir in */; do
    if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
        cd "$dir"
        for dir2 in */; do
            if [ -d "$dir2" ]; then
                cd "$dir2"
                ls -d "$PWD"/*
                cd ..
            fi
        done
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

Note how I've used `if` statements to test each value of `dir` and `dir2` to make sure they are truly directories, and I skip them if they are not.

Also note the `set -evx` line, which are a nice set of options to set when you're first writing/debugging a script:
    `-e` stops on the first error.
    `-v` prints each line before it executes it.
    `-x` prints each line *after* all the various substitutions/expansions have been performed, before executing it.

Also consider spending some time in the `bash(1)` man page looking at shell options like `nullglob` and `failglob`, if you don't like the default globbing behavior of returning the wildcard expression itself when it fails to match anything.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. The code is useful for understanding loop behavior and the recommendation of using 'find' even more.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use multiple asterixes:

```
for dir in */*; do 
    ls -d $PWD/* &
done
```

Use the `&` to run the code parallelised.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done purely with `ls` using Bash's `globstar` option, which can be enabled either system-wide using `.bashrc` or for the current terminal session only:

```
shopt -s globstar # enable the globstar option
ls -d $PWD/** # recursively search through $PWD and subdirectories
```

This sets the Bash `globstar` option for the current terminal session only, and then recursively travels through the $PWD and all its subdirectories.